# .htaccess dynamic url (old site) to static url in magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

Long time reader first time poster.

I have read through what feels like 100's on similar posts trying to make it fit what i am trying to do.

Apologies if its been covered. I believe I have the correct code but it maybe conflicting with something else?

I have old URLs from an old ASP cart and want to 301 redirect to new magneto static pages.
There are only 5 of these URLS so don't need a bulk action.

example:

OLD URL: http://test.com.au/shopcontent.asp?type=FAQ%20and%20Terms
NEW URL: http://test.com.au/privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode

I know that from reading other posts you can not simply use:

```
Redirect 301 /shopcontent.asp?type=FAQ%20and%20Terms /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode
```

So I have worked out that this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=FAQ%20and%20Terms$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopcontent\.asp$ /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

I have also tried removing the %20 for the spaces like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=FAQ\ and\ Terms$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopcontent\.asp$ /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

When I try and access the old URL it just goes to the 404 page. I am using standard .htaccess file that came with Magento (I can post if that helps);

I am using a VPS which mod rewrite is enabled. I have other Redirect 301's for non dynamic URLS.

Are there any logs that I can look at?

Appreciate any help or advice.

Thanks Rudi

ps. I found this post which got me to where i am now

[RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} in mod_rewrite (dynamic to static URL) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544773/rewritecond-query-string-in-mod-rewrite-dynamic-to-static-url-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You cant use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^type=FAQ\%20and\%20Terms$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^shopcontent\.asp$ /privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I assume you mean I can use that rule which you kindly posted. Unfortunately it is still not redirecting - just goest to 404 page. I am completely stumped. I know that the rewrite rule works on my server as I am using it to redirect top level domains. What other info could i provide that would be helpful?

Comment: Are you entering `http://test.com.au/shopcontent.asp?type=FAQ%20and%20Terms` in the browser and getting 404? Is .htaccess enabled on your system?

Comment: Yes definitely (I just cut and paste above to be sure) obviously test.com.au isn't my u domain, but I just changed.   .htacess is on, as I have other redirect 301s working.

Comment: When I tested this rule it worked pretty well on my localhost, so most likely it is some local issue on your setup.

Comment: Could the magento standard .htacess file be causing a conflict?

Comment: You never mentioned magento before. Make sure this rule is **your very first rule**